# DataGridView добавить ComboBox С++

Tags: c++-cli, datagridview, combobox

Доброго дня)
Как добавить комбобокс в ячейку датагридвью ?
И можно ли комбобокс заполнить из структуры ?

Comment: Думаю стоит указать что Вы используете... я полагаю .net

Comment: извините, C++/CLI Windows Forms

Comment: Я пробую так                                             
           DataGridViewComboBoxColumn^ comboboxColumn=gcnew 
           DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
    dataGridView1->Rows->Add(comboboxColumn);

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell^ bautRate = gcnew DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
bautRate->Items->Add("9600");
dataGridView1->Rows[0]->Cells[1] = bautRate;
```